# Sharing authentication between php and python on same domain

Tags: php, python, session, laravel, authentication

I am in the early planning stages for a new project/site. Two-thrids of the application are already written in php/laravel. The new bit will be written in python, most likely with Flask or Cherrypy (I need Nosql access, so Django is out).

The Laravel application is the primary site and manages user signups, authentication, activity streams, and notifications, as well as a general REST Api. This part of the site is already well under development, and so switching to python is not an option.

Both sections would need to feel entirely unified to the end user. The design and themes would be identical. Even the urls would show no difference:

site.com - laravel

site.com/forums - laravel

site.com/login,logout,signup - laravel

site.com/ - laravel

site.com/maker - **python/flask**

I think I have figured out how to serve both from the same server, but how do I share logins? The user should be able to login using laravel and navigate to /maker and still be logged in.

To keep in mind:

- maker will not signup user, only make sure they are logged in. If not, redirect to laravel's login page.
- Also, both have access to the same database.

What are my options here?

Comment: The session ID must be one of your application that controls or defining. Or session ID in the url, you must move the label (the old system). At the time the serious conditions and status transport two separate application requires you to do a comparison. Cookie method you would put your existing applications.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called token based authentication. From what you describe you probably want to do the auth in laravel. I'm not familiar with laravel but some googling found [this tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs).

Comment: @GarryCaims, that looks great. In this case, would it be the front-end javascript that the python modules is serving that would do the authentication? Is there anyway to pass that token down to python and let it decide if the session is valid?

Comment: @Apollo Have you figured out how to share the token between PHP and Flask?

Comment: Not sure if that tutorial will work out. It says in one of the paragraphs:
>Coupling with the web framework: When using server-based authentication we are tied to our framework’s authentication scheme. It is really hard, or even impossible, to share session data between different web frameworks written in different programming languages.